# Sencha Ext Js How to add an object to a Ext.grid.Panel

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

I'm using Sencha Ext Js 4, and I've an Ext.grid.Panel. 
I would add inside the header another element, for example a textbox. Is it possible?

```
{filterable: true, header: 'Unique' /*Here i want add a textbox*/,  dataIndex: 'label', flex: 1, sortable: true}
```

It should look like this image[image: Example].

EDIT:
This is my customized grid:

```
  var grid1 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: getLocalStore(),
    enableLocking: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowexpander',
        rowBodyTpl : new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<p><b>Company:</b> {company}</p>',
            '<p><b>Change:</b> {change:this.formatChange}</p><br>',
            '<p><b>Summary:</b> {desc}</p>',
        {
            formatChange: function(v){
                var color = v >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red';
                return '<span style="color: ' + color + ';">' + Ext.util.Format.usMoney(v) + '</span>';
            }
        })
    }],
    collapsible: true,
    animCollapse: false,
    title: 'Expander Rows in a Collapsible Grid with lockable columns',
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    margin: '0 0 20 0',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    initComponent: function() {

    var filter = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[ftype="filters"]'); 
    filter.local = false;

    console.log('initComponent function in View has been called...');

    this.columns = [
          {tooltip:'The unque id associated with the current node', 
            hidden: true, header: 'id', width: 45, sortable: false, hideable: true, id: 'id'},
          {tooltip:'Friendly name of current node. This can be edited',
              filterable: true, header: [
                                         'Label',{
                                             text: 'action'}

                                         ],  dataIndex: 'label', flex: 1, sortable: true, 
              editor: {
                  xtype: 'textfield',
                  allowBlank: false
              }
          },
          {filterable: true, header: 'Unique', dataIndex: 'address_unique', flex: 1},
          {filterable: true, header: 'Address network', dataIndex: 'address_network', flex: 1},
          {tooltip:'The current node status', 
            filterable: true, header: 'Node status', dataIndex: 'online', flex: 1},
          {tooltip:'Tells whether this node has been accepted or not.', 
            hidden: true, filterable: true, header: 'Accepted', dataIndex: 'accepted', flex: 1},
          {tooltip:'Type of node: this can be a router, a leaf node, a virtual node',
            hidden: true, filterable: true, header: 'Type', dataIndex: 'type', flex: 1}
    ];
    Ext.getStore('M2MResources').guaranteeRange(0, 200);

    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
```

Comment: May I know the reason why you want to go for a text field there?
If you want to put it as a search field which searches in that column then you can go with filters.
Any how we can achieve it.

Comment: Yes but i prefer make searches directly form column in only one click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution i've used. Working well with EXTJS 4.1.x:
Add [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150918-Grid-Header-Filters) plugin (written by D. Zucconi) in the folder:

Ext\ux\grid\plugin

```
 /**
 * Plugin that enable filters on the grid header.<br>
 * The header filters are integrated with new Ext4 <code>Ext.data.Store</code> filters.<br>
 * It enables:
 * <ul>
 * <li>Instances of <code>Ext.form.field.Field</code> subclasses that can be used as filter fields into column header</li>
 * <li>New grid methods to control header filters (get values, update, apply)</li>
 * <li>New grid events to intercept plugin and filters events</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * The plugins also enables the stateful feature for header filters so filter values are stored with grid status if grid is stateful.<br>
 * 
 * # Enable filters on grid columns
 * The plugin checks the <code>filter</code> attribute that can be included into each column configuration.
 * The value of this attribute can be a <code>Ext.form.field.Field</code> configuration or an array of field configurations to enable more
 * than one filter on a single column.<br>
 * Field <code>readOnly</code> and <code>disabled</code> attributes are managed by the plugin to avoid filter update or filter apply.
 * The filter field configuration also supports some special attributes to control filter configuration:
 * <ul>
 * <li>
 *     <code>filterName</code>: the name of the filter that will be used when the filter is applied to store filters (as <code>property</code> of <code>Ext.util.Filter</code> attribute).
 *     If this attribute is not specified the column <code>dataIndex</code> will be used. <b>NOTE</b>: The filter name must be unique in a grid header. The plugin doesn't support correctly filters
 *     with same name.
 * </li>
 * </ul>
 * On the grid configuration the {@link #headerFilters} attribute is supported. The value must be an object with name-values pairs for filters to initialize. 
 * It can be used to initialize header filters in grid configuration.
 * 
 * # Plugin configuration
 * The plugin supports also some configuration attributes that can be specified when the plugin is created (with <code>Ext.create</code>).
 * These parameters are:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link #stateful}: Enables filters save and load when grid status is managed by <code>Ext.state.Manager</code>. If the grid is not stateful this parameter has no effects</li>
 * <li>{@link #reloadOnChange}: Intercepts the special {@link #headerfilterchange} plugin-enabled grid event and automatically reload or refresh grid Store. Default true</li>
 * <li>{@link #ensureFilteredVisible}: If one filter on column is active, the plugin ensures that this column is not hidden (if can be made visible).</li>
 * <li>{@link #enableTooltip}: Enable active filters description tootip on grid header</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * # Enabled grid methods
 * <ul>
 *     <li><code>setHeaderFilter(name, value, reset)</code>: Set a single filter value</li>
 *     <li><code>setHeaderFilters(filters, reset)</code>: Set header filters</li>
 *     <li><code>getHeaderFilters()</code>: Set header filters</li>
 *     <li><code>getHeaderFilterField(filterName)</code>: To access filter field</li>
 *     <li><code>resetHeaderFilters()</code>: Resets filter fields calling reset() method of each one</li>
 *     <li><code>clearHeaderFilters()</code>: Clears filter fields</li>
 *     <li><code>applyHeaderFilters()</code>: Applies filters values to Grid Store. The store will be also refreshed or reloaded if {@link #reloadOnChange} is true</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * # Enabled grid events
 * <ul>
 *     <li>{@link #headerfilterchange} : fired by Grid when some header filter changes value</li>
 *     <li>{@link #headerfiltersrender} : fired by Grid when header filters are rendered</li>
 *     <li>{@link #beforeheaderfiltersapply} : fired before filters are applied to Grid Store</li>
 *     <li>{@link #headerfiltersapply} : fired after filters are applied to Grid Store</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @author Damiano Zucconi - http://www.isipc.it
 * @version 0.2.0
 */
Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.plugin.HeaderFilters',{

    ptype: 'gridheaderfilters',

    alternateClassName: ['Ext.ux.grid.HeaderFilters', 'Ext.ux.grid.header.Filters'],

    requires: [
        'Ext.container.Container',
        'Ext.tip.ToolTip'
    ],




    grid: null,

    fields: null,

    containers: null,

    storeLoaded: false,

    filterFieldCls: 'x-gridheaderfilters-filter-field',

    filterContainerCls: 'x-gridheaderfilters-filter-container',

    filterRoot: 'data',

    tooltipTpl: '{[Ext.isEmpty(values.filters) ? this.text.noFilter : "<b>"+this.text.activeFilters+"</b>"]}<br><tpl for="filters"><tpl if="value != \'\'">{[values.label ? values.label : values.property]} = {value}<br></tpl></tpl>',

    lastApplyFilters: null,

    bundle: {
        activeFilters: 'Active filters',
        noFilter: 'No filter'
    },

    /**
    * @cfg {Boolean} stateful
    * Specifies if headerFilters values are saved into grid status when filters changes.
    * This configuration can be overridden from grid configuration parameter <code>statefulHeaderFilters</code> (if defined).
    * Used only if grid <b>is stateful</b>. Default = true.
    * 
    */
    stateful: true,

   /**
   * @cfg {Boolean} reloadOnChange
   * Specifies if the grid store will be auto-reloaded when filters change. The store
   * will be reloaded only if is was already loaded. If the store is local or it doesn't has remote filters
   * the store will be always updated on filters change.
   * 
   */
   reloadOnChange: true,

    /**
   * @cfg {Boolean} ensureFilteredVisible
   * If the column on wich the filter is set is hidden and can be made visible, the
   * plugin makes the column visible.
   */
    ensureFilteredVisible: true,

    /**
    * @cfg {Boolean} enableTooltip
    * If a tooltip with active filters description must be enabled on the grid header
    */
    enableTooltip: true,

    statusProperty: 'headerFilters',

    rendered: false,

   constructor: function(cfg) 
   {
       if(cfg)
       {
        Ext.apply(this,cfg);
       }
   },

   init: function(grid)
   {
       this.grid = grid;

        /*var storeProxy = this.grid.getStore().getProxy();
        if(storeProxy && storeProxy.getReader())
        {
            var reader = storeProxy.getReader();
            this.filterRoot = reader.root ? reader.root : undefined;
        }*/
        /**
         * @cfg {Object} headerFilters
         * <b>Configuration attribute for grid</b>
         * Allows to initialize header filters values from grid configuration.
         * This object must have filter names as keys and filter values as values.
         * If this plugin has {@link #stateful} enabled, the saved filters have priority and override these filters.
         * Use {@link #ignoreSavedHeaderFilters} to ignore current status and apply these filters directly.
         */
       if(!grid.headerFilters)
           grid.headerFilters = {};


       if(Ext.isBoolean(grid.statefulHeaderFilters))
       {
           this.setStateful(grid.statefulHeaderFilters);
       }

        this.grid.addEvents(
      /**
        * @event headerfilterchange
        * <b>Event enabled on the Grid</b>: fired when at least one filter is updated after apply.
        * @param {Ext.grid.Panel} grid The grid
        * @param {Ext.util.MixedCollection} filters The applied filters (after apply). Ext.util.Filter objects.
        * @param {Ext.util.MixedCollection} prevFilters The old applied filters (before apply). Ext.util.Filter objects.
        * @param {Number} active Number of active filters (not empty)
        * @param {Ext.data.Store} store Current grid store
        */    
        'headerfilterchange',
        /**
         * @event headerfiltersrender
         * <b>Event enabled on the Grid</b>: fired when filters are rendered
         * @param {Ext.grid.Panel} grid The grid
         * @param {Object} fields The filter fields rendered. The object has for keys the filters names and for value Ext.form.field.Field objects.
         * @param {Object} filters Current header filters. The object has for keys the filters names and for value the filters values.
        */
            'headerfiltersrender',
            /**
         * @event beforeheaderfiltersapply
         * <b>Event enabled on the Grid</b>: fired before filters are confirmed. If the handler returns false no filter apply occurs.
         * @param {Ext.grid.Panel} grid The grid
         * @param {Object} filters Current header filters. The object has for keys the filters names and for value the filters values.
         * @param {Ext.data.Store} store Current grid store
         */
        'beforeheaderfiltersapply',
        /**
         * @event headerfiltersapply
         *<b>Event enabled on the Grid</b>: fired when filters are confirmed.
         * @param {Ext.grid.Panel} grid The grid
         * @param {Object} filters Current header filters. The object has for keys the filters names and for value the filters values.
         * @param {Number} active Number of active filters (not empty)
         * @param {Ext.data.Store} store Current grid store
         */
        'headerfiltersapply'
        );

        this.grid.on({
            scope: this,
            columnresize: this.resizeFilterContainer,
            beforedestroy: this.onDestroy,
            beforestatesave: this.saveFilters,
            afterlayout: this.adjustFilterWidth
        });

        this.grid.headerCt.on({
            scope: this,
            afterrender: this.renderFilters
        });

        this.grid.getStore().on({
            scope: this,
            load: this.onStoreLoad
        });

        if(this.reloadOnChange)
        {
            this.grid.on('headerfilterchange',this.reloadStore, this);
        }

        if(this.stateful)
        {
            this.grid.addStateEvents('headerfilterchange');
        }

        //Enable new grid methods
        Ext.apply(this.grid, 
        {
            headerFilterPlugin: this,
            setHeaderFilter: function(sName, sValue)
            {
                if(!this.headerFilterPlugin)
                    return;
                var fd = {};
                fd[sName] = sValue;
                this.headerFilterPlugin.setFilters(fd);
            },
            /**
             * Returns a collection of filters corresponding to enabled header filters.
             * If a filter field is disabled, the filter is not included.
             * <b>This method is enabled on Grid</b>.
             * @method
             * @return {Array[Ext.util.Filter]} An array of Ext.util.Filter
             */
            getHeaderFilters: function()
            {
                if(!this.headerFilterPlugin)
                    return null;
                return this.headerFilterPlugin.getFilters();
            },
            /**
             * Set header filter values
             * <b>Method enabled on Grid</b>
             * @method
             * @param {Object or Array[Object]} filters An object with key/value pairs or an array of Ext.util.Filter objects (or corresponding configuration).
             * Only filters that matches with header filters names will be set
             */
            setHeaderFilters: function(obj)
            {
                if(!this.headerFilterPlugin)
                    return;
                this.headerFilterPlugin.setFilters(obj);
            },
            getHeaderFilterField: function(fn)
            {
                if(!this.headerFilterPlugin)
                    return;
                if(this.headerFilterPlugin.fields[fn])
                    return this.headerFilterPlugin.fields[fn];
                else
                    return null;
            },
            resetHeaderFilters: function()
            {
                if(!this.headerFilterPlugin)
                    return;
                this.headerFilterPlugin.resetFilters();
            },
            clearHeaderFilters: function()
            {
                if(!this.headerFilterPlugin)
                    return;
                this.headerFilterPlugin.clearFilters();
            },
            applyHeaderFilters: function()
            {
                if(!this.headerFilterPlugin)
                    return;
                this.headerFilterPlugin.applyFilters();
            }
        });
   },



    saveFilters: function(grid, status)
    {
        status[this.statusProperty] = (this.stateful && this.rendered) ? this.parseFilters() : grid[this.statusProperty];
    },

    setFieldValue: function(field, value)
    {
        var column = field.column;
        if(!Ext.isEmpty(value))
        {
            field.setValue(value);
            if(!Ext.isEmpty(value) && column.hideable && !column.isVisible() && !field.isDisabled() && this.ensureFilteredVisible)
            {
                column.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            field.setValue('');
        }
    },

    renderFilters: function()
    {
        this.destroyFilters();

        this.fields = {};
        this.containers = {};




        var filters = this.grid.headerFilters;

        /**
         * @cfg {Boolean} ignoreSavedHeaderFilters
         * <b>Configuration parameter for grid</b>
         * Allows to ignore saved filter status when {@link #stateful} is enabled.
         * This can be useful to use {@link #headerFilters} configuration directly and ignore status.
         * The state will still be saved if {@link #stateful} is enabled.
         */
        if(this.stateful && this.grid[this.statusProperty] && !this.grid.ignoreSavedHeaderFilters)
        {
            Ext.apply(filters, this.grid[this.statusProperty]);
        }

        var storeFilters = this.parseStoreFilters();
        filters = Ext.apply(storeFilters, filters);

        var columns = this.grid.headerCt.getGridColumns(true);
        for(var c=0; c < columns.length; c++)
        {
            var column = columns[c];
            if(column.filter)
            {
                var filterContainerConfig = {
                    itemId: column.id + '-filtersContainer',
                    cls: this.filterContainerCls,
                    layout: 'anchor',
                    bodyStyle: {'background-color': 'transparent'},
                    border: false,
                    width: column.getWidth(),
                    listeners: {
                        scope: this,
                        element: 'el',
                        mousedown: function(e)
                        {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        },
                        click: function(e)
                        {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        },
                        keydown: function(e){
                             e.stopPropagation();
                        },
                        keypress: function(e){
                             e.stopPropagation();
                             if(e.getKey() == Ext.EventObject.ENTER)
                             {
                                 this.onFilterContainerEnter();
                             }
                        },
                        keyup: function(e){
                             e.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    },
                    items: []
                }

                var fca = [].concat(column.filter);

                for(var ci = 0; ci < fca.length; ci++)
                {
                    var fc = fca[ci];
                    Ext.applyIf(fc, {
                        filterName: column.dataIndex,
                        fieldLabel: column.text || column.header,
                        hideLabel: fca.length == 1
                    });
                    var initValue = Ext.isEmpty(filters[fc.filterName]) ? null : filters[fc.filterName];
                    Ext.apply(fc, {
                        cls: this.filterFieldCls,
                        itemId: fc.filterName,
                        anchor: '-1'
                    });
                    var filterField = Ext.ComponentManager.create(fc);
                    filterField.column = column;
                    this.setFieldValue(filterField, initValue);
                    this.fields[filterField.filterName] = filterField;
                    filterContainerConfig.items.push(filterField);
                }

                var filterContainer = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', filterContainerConfig);
                filterContainer.render(column.el);
                this.containers[column.id] = filterContainer;
                column.setPadding = Ext.Function.createInterceptor(column.setPadding, function(h){return false});
            }
        }

        if(this.enableTooltip)
        {
            this.tooltipTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(this.tooltipTpl,{text: this.bundle});
            this.tooltip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip',{
                target: this.grid.headerCt.el,
                //delegate: '.'+this.filterContainerCls,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                html: this.tooltipTpl.apply({filters: []})
            });        
            this.grid.on('headerfilterchange',function(grid, filters)
            {
                var sf = filters.filterBy(function(filt){
                    return !Ext.isEmpty(filt.value);
                });
                this.tooltip.update(this.tooltipTpl.apply({filters: sf.getRange()}));
            },this);
        }

        this.applyFilters();
        this.rendered = true;
        this.grid.fireEvent('headerfiltersrender',this.grid,this.fields,this.parseFilters());
    },

    onStoreLoad: function()
    {
        this.storeLoaded = true;
    },

    onFilterContainerEnter: function()
    {
        this.applyFilters();
    },

    resizeFilterContainer: function(headerCt,column,w,opts)
    {
         if(!this.containers)             return;
        var cnt = this.containers[column.id];
        if(cnt)
        {
            cnt.setWidth(w);
            cnt.doLayout();
        }
    },

    destroyFilters: function()
    {
        this.rendered = false;
         if(this.fields)
         {
             for(var f in this.fields)
                 Ext.destroy(this.fields[f]);
             delete this.fields;
         }

         if(this.containers)
         {
             for(var c in this.containers)
                 Ext.destroy(this.containers[c]);
             delete this.containers;
         }
    },

    onDestroy: function()
    {
        this.destroyFilters();
        Ext.destroy(this.tooltip, this.tooltipTpl);
    },

     adjustFilterWidth: function() 
    {
        if(!this.containers) return;
        var columns = this.grid.headerCt.getGridColumns(true);        
        for(var c=0; c < columns.length; c++) 
        {           
            var column = columns[c];            
            if (column.filter && column.flex) 
            {               
                this.containers[column.id].setWidth(column.getWidth()-1);            
            }
        }
     },

    resetFilters: function()
    {
        if(!this.fields)
            return;
        for(var fn in this.fields)
        {
            var f = this.fields[fn];
            if(!f.isDisabled() && !f.readOnly && Ext.isFunction(f.reset))
                f.reset();
        }
        this.applyFilters();
    },

    clearFilters: function()
    {
        if(!this.fields)
            return;
        for(var fn in this.fields)
        {
            var f = this.fields[fn];
            if(!f.isDisabled() && !f.readOnly)
                f.setValue('');
        }
        this.applyFilters();
    },

    setFilters: function(filters)
    {
        if(!filters)
            return;

        if(Ext.isArray(filters))
        {
            var conv = {};
            Ext.each(filters, function(filter){
                if(filter.property)
                {
                    conv[filter.property] = filter.value; 
                }
            });
            filters = conv;
        }
        else if(!Ext.isObject(filters))
        {
            return;
        }




        this.initFilterFields(filters);
        this.applyFilters();
    },

    getFilters: function()
    {
        var filters = this.parseFilters();
        var res = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();
        for(var fn in filters)
        {
            var value = filters[fn];
            var field = this.fields[fn];
            res.add(new Ext.util.Filter({
                property: fn,
                value: value,
                root: this.filterRoot,
                label: field.fieldLabel
            }));
        }
        return res;
    },

    parseFilters: function()
    {
        var filters = {};
        if(!this.fields)
            return filters;
        for(var fn in this.fields)
        {
            var field = this.fields[fn];
            if(!field.isDisabled() && field.isValid())
                filters[field.filterName] = field.getSubmitValue();
        }
        return filters;
    },

    initFilterFields: function(filters)
    {
        if(!this.fields)
            return;




        for(var fn in  filters)
        {
            var value = filters[fn];
            var field = this.fields[fn];
            if(field)
            {
                this.setFieldValue(filterField, initValue);
            }
        }
    },

    countActiveFilters: function()
    {
        var fv = this.parseFilters();
        var af = 0;
        for(var fn in fv)
        {
            if(!Ext.isEmpty(fv[fn]))
                af ++;
        }
        return af;
    },

    parseStoreFilters: function()
    {
        var sf = this.grid.getStore().filters;
        var res = {};
        sf.each(function(filter){
            var name = filter.property;
            var value = filter.value;
            if(name && value)
            {
                res[name] = value;            
            }
        });
        return res;
    },

    applyFilters: function()
    {
        var filters = this.parseFilters();
        if(this.grid.fireEvent('beforeheaderfiltersapply', this.grid, filters, this.grid.getStore()) !== false)
        {
            var storeFilters = this.grid.getStore().filters;
            var exFilters = storeFilters.clone();
            var change = false;
            var active = 0;
            for(var fn in filters)
            {
                var value = filters[fn];

                var sf = storeFilters.findBy(function(filter){
                    return filter.property == fn;
                });

                if(Ext.isEmpty(value))
                {
                    if(sf)
                    {
                        storeFilters.remove(sf);
                        change = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var field = this.fields[fn];
                    if(!sf || sf.value != filters[fn])
                    {
                        var newSf = new Ext.util.Filter({
                            root: this.filterRoot,
                            property: fn,
                            value: filters[fn],
                            label: field.fieldLabel
                        });
                        if(sf)
                        {
                            storeFilters.remove(sf);
                        }
                        storeFilters.add(newSf);
                        change = true;
                    }
                    active ++;
                }
            }

            this.grid.fireEvent('headerfiltersapply', this.grid, filters, active, this.grid.getStore());
            if(change)
            {
                var curFilters = this.getFilters();
                this.grid.fireEvent('headerfilterchange', this.grid, curFilters, this.lastApplyFilters, active, this.grid.getStore());
                this.lastApplyFilters = curFilters;
            }
        }
    },

    reloadStore: function()
    {
        var gs = this.grid.getStore();
        if(this.grid.getStore().remoteFilter)
        {
            if(this.storeLoaded)
            {
                gs.currentPage = 1;
                gs.load();
            }
        }
        else
      {
            if(gs.filters.getCount()) 
         {
                if(!gs.snapshot)
                    gs.snapshot = gs.data.clone();
                else
                {
                    gs.currentPage = 1;
                }
            gs.data = gs.snapshot.filter(gs.filters.getRange());
            var doLocalSort = gs.sortOnFilter && !gs.remoteSort;
            if(doLocalSort)
                {
                    gs.sort();
                }
            // fire datachanged event if it hasn't already been fired by doSort
            if (!doLocalSort || gs.sorters.length < 1) 
            {
                gs.fireEvent('datachanged', gs);
                }
            }
           else
           {
                if(gs.snapshot)
                {
                    gs.currentPage = 1;
                    gs.data = gs.snapshot.clone();
                 delete gs.snapshot;
                 gs.fireEvent('datachanged', gs);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Add in your grid class the following rows:

- plugin for the grid:

  ```
  plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.ux.grid.plugin.HeaderFilters')/*, ... other plugins here */]
  ```
- column configuration:

  ```
  columns:[{ /*other configurations for your column:*/
         header: 'Accepted', dataIndex: 'accepted', flex: 1,
         /*filter plugin configuration:*/
         filterable: true, filter:{xtype: 'textfield' /* i've used a simple textbox*/}}
         /*, other columns here */]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I have a working code here for ExtJs 3,

may be you need to do certain changes to make it to Extjs 4.

```
/****************************************************
 * Filter row class.
 * @class Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow
 ************************************************/
Ext.namespace('Ext.ux.grid');
Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow = function(config) {
    Ext.apply(this, config);
    this.addEvents(
        "change"
    );
    Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow.superclass.constructor.call(this);
};

Ext.extend(Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow, Ext.util.Observable, {    
    init: function(grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
         this.grid.addClass('filter-row');
        var view = grid.getView();
        var headerTpl = new Ext.Template(
            '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="{tstyle}">',
                '<thead><tr class="x-grid3-hd-row  ">{cells}</tr></thead>',
            "</table>"
        );
        Ext.applyIf(view, { templates: {} });
        view.templates.header = headerTpl;
        view.templates.hcell = new Ext.Template(
            '<td class="x-grid3-hd x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-{id} {css}" style="{style}">',
                '<div {tooltip} {attr} class="x-grid3-hd-inner x-grid3-hd-{id}" unselectable="on" style="{istyle}">',
                    '<span style="cursor:hand">{value}</span>&#160;&#160;',
                    '<img id="'+grid.id+'-SortImg-{id}" src="Images/Setting.gif" />',
                    '<div class="x-small-editor filterInput" id="'+grid.id+'-filter-{id}"></div>',
                '</div>',
            '</td>'
        ); 

        Ext.applyIf(view, { templates: {} });
        view.templates.header = headerTpl;

        grid.on('resize', this.syncFields, this);
        grid.on('columnresize', this.syncFields, this);
        grid.on('render', this.renderFields, this);
        // private
        var FilterRow = this;
        view.updateHeaders = function(){
            this.innerHd.firstChild.innerHTML = this.renderHeaders();
            this.innerHd.firstChild.style.width = this.getOffsetWidth();
            this.innerHd.firstChild.firstChild.style.width = this.getTotalWidth();
            FilterRow.renderFields();
        };
        Ext.apply(grid, {
            enableColumnHide_: false,
            enableColumnMove: false
        });

         this.on('change', function(){
            Ext.getBody().mask('Loading Please Wait...','x-mask-loading');
            var filterRecord = getData(grid);
            var wfStatus = 1;
            for(var i=0;i<filterRecord.length;i++)
            {
            var filterColumn = filterRecord[i].filterColumn;
                if(filterColumn == "FormStatus")
                {
                    var Status = filterRecord[i].filterText;
                    if(Status == "10")
                        wfStatus = 2;   
                }
            }
            getFilterXML(1,gblPageCount,0,chevronId,"",wfStatus,0,grid,filterRecord);

        }, grid); 

         grid.on('keypress', function(e){
            if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) { 
            Ext.getBody().mask('Loading Please Wait...','x-mask-loading');
            var filterRecord = getData(grid);
            getFilterXML(1,gblPageCount,0,chevronId,"","",0,grid,filterRecord);

        }
        }, grid); 
    },

    renderFields: function() {          
        var grid = this.grid;
        var filterRow = this;
        var cm = grid.getColumnModel();
        var cols = cm.config;
        var gridId = grid.id;
        Ext.each(cols, function(col) {
            if (!col.hidden) {
                var filterDivId = gridId + "-filter-" + col.id;
                var sortImgId = grid.id+"-SortImg-"+ col.id;
                var editor      = col.filter;
                var clearFilter = col.clearFilter;
                if (editor) {
                    if(Ext.isIE){
                        col.filter = editor = editor.cloneConfig({value:editor.getValue()});
                    }
                    if (editor.getXType() == 'combo') {
                        editor.on('select', this.resetNoFilterOption, this, editor);
                    } else {
                    editor.on("keypress", this.onKeyPress, this);
                    }
                    new Ext.Panel({border:false, layout:'fit', items:editor, renderTo:filterDivId});
                }
                if(col.sortIcon)
                        document.getElementById(sortImgId).src =   col.sortIcon ;
            }
        }, this);
    },

    onKeyPress: function(field, e) {
        this.fireEvent("keypress", { filter: this });
    },

    resetNoFilterOption: function(editor) {
        if(editor.filterOption=='NoFilter'){//if filter value have been changed , but "NoFilter" menu is still selected then reset it 
            editor.filterOption = '';
        }
        this.onChange();
    },
    onChange: function() {  
        this.fireEvent("change", { filter: this });
    },

    clearFilters: function() {
        this.fireEvent("change", { filter: this, data: {} });
    },

    syncFields: function() {
        var grid = this.grid;
        var cm = grid.getColumnModel();
        var cols = cm.config;
        Ext.each(cols, function(col) {
            if (!col.hidden) {              
                var editor = col.filter; 
                if (editor) {
                    editor.setSize(col.width - 18);
                }else if(col.clearFilter && col.clearFilter.setSize){
                     col.clearFilter.setSize(col.width - 10);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: where I have to add it... i'll post my grid class in the first post

Comment: You just need to create a local filterrow,


    var filterRow = new Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow();


and add as a plugin to your grid,



plugins: [filterRow],

Comment: Looking outside of stackoverflow this is the correct way to do that, however in my case it's not working, and i haven't found a way to make it working. The runtime error i'm having is "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)". I've tryed several time to edit your solution (for example refactoring your class), but it make other runtime errors. However i'll upvote your solution because i think it's the correct way to develop this feature.